# Cannot properly remove password protected network sharing on Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-8.1, passwords, network-shares

I have recently setup a computer running Windows 8.1 Pro to act as a home NAS. I have shares and accounts created such that if people in the house login, they get access to their respective shares. As it is, however, in order to connect to the computer you have to supply login information in a "Enter  network credentials" dialogue box. I would like people to be able to get in to view the public folder and just see the shares without needing to login, until you want to access your own share.

I have tried disabling password protected sharing from within the Network and Sharing centre, as well as the extra solution discussed [here](https://www.supportrix.com/kb/what-to-do-if-you-cannot-turn-off-password-protected-sharing-in-windows-8/), but nothing works. I still get the login dialogue just as I would before.

Any help is much appreciated!